# What Wi-Fi network am I connected to?

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm using Ubuntu Server 18.04 (Bionic). How can I tell what wi-fi network I am connected to from the command line?

Ideally I would like to be able to do so without installing any new packages. I don't have confidence that many of the installable tools that exist for managing Wi-Fi networks are considered best practices on this version of Ubuntu. I am also concerned about some new tool deciding to take over management of my network interfaces which is otherwise working pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu Bionic, I seem to be running `networkd` and `wpa_supplicant`. I found that I could run:

```
sudo wpa_cli -i wlan0 list_networks
```

The current network will be marked `[CURRENT]`. However, the interface must be supplied with `-i`, as the default interface is not the one that is actually in use.

Comment: can you try `nmcli device wifi list`?

Comment: No, because `nmcli` expects that I have `network-manager` installed, which is not the default on Ubuntu Server 18.04.

Comment: Thank you.. Its clear now..